# Stripping and adding the same type to a type union does not yield the original type

Tags: typescript

I have a problem with stripping and then adding a type again:

```
type NotNull<T> = T extends null ? never : T;

type MaybeNull<T> = T | null;

type Foo<T> = MaybeNull<NotNull<T>>;
```

The compiler simplifies Foo to:

```
type Foo<T> = NotNull<T> | null
```

But, I would expect:

```
type Foo<T> = T | null
```

That is causing some trouble somewhere in my code. Any idea how to fix that?

**EDIT**

```
interface Foo<T> {
  bar(): MaybeNull<T>;
}

class Bar<T> implements Foo<NotNull<T>> {
  public bar(): MaybeNull<T> {
    return null;
  }
}
```

The compiler complains with:

```
Property 'bar' in type 'Bar<T>' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Foo<NotNull<T>>'.
  Type '() => MaybeNull<T>' is not assignable to type '() => MaybeNull<NotNull<T>>'.
    Type 'MaybeNull<T>' is not assignable to type 'MaybeNull<NotNull<T>>'.
      Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'MaybeNull<NotNull<T>>'.
        Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'NotNull<T>'.
```

I know that the example might look a bit artifical, but the actual type hierarchy looks much more complex...

Comment: *That is causing some trouble somewhere in my code* - then the answer would be *This can be fixed by adding something somewhere in your code*. The compiler works as it should, it does a logically correct output, there is nothing to *fix* from compiler's side. What is the problem you want to solve?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to fix. A conditional is not resolved until a concrete type is provided. So the compiler simplifies best it can. When you provide an actual value for `T` the conditional will be resolved and you get the expected result

```
type FooString = Foo<string> //string | null
```

If this is causing problems in some way, post that code and we will see how (and if) we can work around it, but generally unresolved conditionals will not get simplified.